# signature issue while installing influxdb2 on ubuntu20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, apt-get, influxdb-2

I am trying to install influxdb2 with the link   [install influxdb2 on ubuntu 20.04](https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-influxdb2-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-step-by-step/)
but got signature related issue as below. Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

```
/home/ravi>sudo su
/home/ravi#wget -qO- https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg > /dev/null
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/ravi//.gnupg'
/home/ravi#export DISTRIB_ID=$(lsb_release -si); export DISTRIB_CODENAME=$(lsb_release -sc)
/home/ravi#echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/${DISTRIB_ID,,} ${DISTRIB_CODENAME} stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdb.list > /dev/null
/home/ravi#apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                           
Get:4 https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [7,019 B]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Err:4 https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                               
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
Hit:2 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                                                                                 
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.0 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [275 kB]                
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [588 kB]                     
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [409 kB]                                      
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [812 kB]                       
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [94.7 kB]                        
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]           
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,992 B]             
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                             
W: GPG error: https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
E: The repository 'https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
/home/ravi#apt-get install influxdb2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package influxdb2
/home/ravi#
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the instructions at https://repos.influxdata.com/. It seems like the key to use now is `https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive.key` (or if that doesn't work, `https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive_compat.key`).